# I want to delete a folder if it is empty and also it should not delete the folder and it's sub folder and files inside if it is not empty

Tags: xml, ant

I have this Directory: D:\Rahul\DIspatcher\Logs

So, if Logs is empty then Log folder should be deleted

Expected result: D:\Rahul\DIspatcher

if I have this Directory : D:\Rahul\DIspatcher\Logs\log1.txt

Expected result:  D:\Rahul\DIspatcher\Logs\log1.txt

I tried this code code :

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
   <fileset dir="D:\Rahul\DIspatcher\Logs" includes="D:\Rahul\DIspatcher\Logs" defaultexcludes="false"/>
</delete>
```

this piece of code  is working if folder is not empty.
but when it is empty this code is not helping me to delete the folder.

we can't use if inside delete as in Ant.

Could you please help me fix this

**I'm new to Ant**

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this would be to rely on the default behavior of the `delete` task with a nested `dirset`.

```
<target name="delete-only-empty-dirs">

    <!-- Setup -->

    <delete dir="empty-dir" includeemptydirs="true" />
    <delete dir="content-dir" includeemptydirs="true" />

    <mkdir dir="empty-dir" />
    <mkdir dir="content-dir" />
    <touch file="content-dir/file.txt" />

    <!-- Delete Empty -->

    <delete failonerror="false">
        <dirset dir="empty-dir" />
    </delete>
    <delete failonerror="false">
        <dirset dir="content-dir" />
    </delete>
</target>
```

In the above example, only `empty-dir` will be deleted at the end of the script, while `content-dir` and the file it contains will be left alone.

Comment: I got your point, What if Folder does not exists at all in that case i should not get any error for that. How can we handle that ?

Comment: @RahulKumar The delete task will not fail if there's nothing to delete.

Comment: After I submitted the Change package it got failed Saying the error like this:                      failed with Directory does not exist: C:\Apps\tc\tc2312\DISPAT~1\Logs

Comment: My bad, I forgot we were using a nested `dirset`, in which case delete will fail when the resource collection cannot be resolved. To avoid this, you can add `failonerror="false"` to the delete task (updated the answer to reflect this).

Comment: Thanks  @CAustin. I after seeing your suggestion I have added this code and it worked for me. 
                        <if>
                            <isset property="folder.exists" />
                            <then>
                                <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                                    <fileset dir="${fnd0_dispatcherclientLogDir}" includes="**" excludes="**/*.*" />
                                </delete>
                            </then>
                        </if>

Comment: @RahulKumar I highly recommend *against* using ant-contrib's `if`/`then`/`else` tags. It will almost always lead to confusing, messy build scripts in the long run. If your script must have conditional steps, you should use `<target>`'s `if` attribute along with the `condition` task instead.